# Separate String into two parts

Tags: java

My `String` looks like this: `"/namestart blabla1 /nameend blabla2"`.
PS. it might also be `/namestartblabla1/nameendbababa2` for example.

I need to get those into two strings:

```
string1 == blabla1
string2 == blabla2
```

I got my strings like this:

```
if(mystring.startsWith("/namestart")){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/namestart(.*?)/nameend");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mystring);
    if (m.find()) {
      String string1 = m.group(1);
      String string2 = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf("/nameend")+8, mystring.length()));
    }
}
```

First question is can that be done better or is this solution OK?

And second problem is that blabla1 and blabla2 can be anything, it can even be /nameend (probaby wont be) or something that would screw up my reg expression. What would be the theoretical solution for that?

Comment: Where do those strings come from?

Comment: Is your string always in format `/namestart`blabla1 `/nameend`blabla2? Also you mentioned that `blabla1` and `blabla2` can be even `/nameend`. What output you expect  for that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but maybe try using `groups` indexes instead of `substring`. To get rid of `if(mystring.startsWith("/namestart")){` you can also use `^` anchor at star of your regex to indicate that matching part should also be placed at start of the string.

```
String mystring = "/namestart blabla1 /nameend blabla2";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(/namestart)(.*?)(/nameend)(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mystring);
if (m.find()) {
    String string1 = m.group(2);
    String string2 = m.group(4);
    System.out.println(string1 + "|" + string2);
}
```

output

```
 blabla1 | blabla2
```

---

Also depending on what you are trying to achieve in situation where `blabla1` or `blabla2` would be `/nameend` you can try changing `(.*?)` into `(.+?)`.

Comment: Thanks, i think thats what im looking for.
May i please ask you to explain this expression to me:
"^(/namestart)(.*?)(/nameend)(.*)"
and also what would replacement with (.+?) mean?

Comment: `.*?` and `.+?` are exactly equivalent to `.*`.  They all match literally any string.

Comment: @user1985273 could you say what part of regex is not clear to you? I can see that in your questions you used groups `(...)` and reluctant quantifier `(.*?)` so I am not sure what part is new to you.

Comment: @user1985273 BTW difference between `(.*?)` and `(.+?)` would be seen in situation like this `/namestart/nameend/nameend`. For `(.*?)` it will return empty string representing  `/namestart(this)/nameend/nameend` place (because `*` means 0 or more), and for `(.+?)` it would return part I will mark with []  `/namestart[/nameend]/nameend` (+ means one or more occurrences)

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the string is always as follows,

```
String Str = new String("/namestart blabla1 /nameend blabla2");
```

Then the following code might be sufficient,

```
      for (String temp: Str.split(" ", 4)){
         System.out.println(temp);
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, didnt mention it might also be /namestartblabla1/nameendbababa2 for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at the code below for your solution

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mystring = "/namestart hello /nameend test";

        if(mystring.startsWith("/namestart") && mystring.contains("/nameend")){
        System.out.println("String 1: " + mystring.substring(10, mystring.lastIndexOf("/nameend")).trim());
        System.out.println("String 2: " + mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("/nameend") + 8).trim());
        }

    }
}
```

We have to assume that last '/nameend' will be the key for last name as I can see that mystring can be '/namestartblabla1/nameend/nameendbababa2' this also. Here it is difficult to tell that which '/nameend' is the key and which is value. Using the code above you will get

String1 : blabla1/nameend
String2 : bababa2

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, cleanest approach is to  use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] parts = mystring.split("\\s*/name(end|start)\\s*");
String string1 = parts[1];
String string2 = parts[2];
```

The regex passed to `split()`specifies the separator, which is consumed, so by including optional whitespace before and after the delimiting strings, leading and trailing blanks around the strings are automatically removed.